# Azure data transfer Identity Column Seed Jumped by 10,000

Tags: sql, azure, sql-server-2012

After inserting the data via sql script
that had

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[table] ON
...
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[table] OFF
```

the identity seed has increased by 10,000

I have tried running reseed

```
dbcc CHECKIDENT ('vendors', 'reseed', 57439)
```

but I get the error saying the    DBCC command 'CHECKIDENT' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.

How to stop in the future this problem?

Comment: this question is answered here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/61f3875f-9b10-4e2c-8501-e325fa17e5a7/azure-database-identity-field-jump

Comment: Frank, do not really see any solution at the link you provided. The discussion does mention the same problem and same solution to reseed that does not work on Azure.
I did SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF and ON when i was importing data and I did pick SQL Azure as type of sql to generate in Advanced options. Still looking for a solution to fix it and to avoid in the future.

Comment: There is an issue with SQL SERVER 2012. where it's done by design to improve the performance.
I do not about everybody else but its very inconvinient to have records jump by 1000 every few days.
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/alwayson-failover-results-in-reseed-of-identity

Comment: That happens every time the SQL Service restarts. If Azure allowed Sequences it could be fixed, but since it doesn't allow, the only workaround I guess is to create a table (for each identity) with the current number, and a procedure to insert elements that reads this number, increments and then insert in the table...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found [this post](http://www.networksteve.com/forum/topic.php/Identity_/_Primary_Key_field_in_SQL_Azure_skipping_large_blocks/?TopicId=37864&Posts=24) on the web.

> The behavior (reseed) is by design, but has been acknowledged
>   internally as less than optimal and a request has been made (again,
>   internally) to change the behavior. This may or may not happen.
>
> The reseed is triggered by instance bounces, which are covered by the
>   SLA. They are mostly patches to the OS or SQL Azure itself.
>
> The most important point was that, chances are, we will never hit the
>   int limit. I think we all are forgetting (at least I did) that
>   SQLAzure is not like SQL Server; there are very real limits in place,
>   specifically total db size (150 gigs). He also said there is a max row
>   limit per table of 10 million records, but I'm not finding
>   documentation of that on the web. Assuming that is correct, even with
>   jumps of 1000k, we would still be safe. And yes you could also switch
>   to a bigint if you hit the int limit before the total db size limit.
>   His point was simply that we will run out of room before we hit the
>   int limit.

The Limits on SQL Azure could change, but I guess the point is you can get the large gaps if the SQL instance crashes.